# What is Ø in tex?

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

I want to reference zeroMQ in my article and wonder how Zero (Ø) as in

[image]

zero mq logo looks like in tex (something like `\zero`)?

Comment: Use `\O`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol

Comment: Hi there, I edited your post to include the screenshot. Welcome to tex exchange; have a look at this post, and see if it helps [how-to-look-up-a-symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)